# Bash: redirect input from 2 sources?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to execute a Linux command in Bash with the input coming from a file or echo, and then switch back to standard input as if the command's input was not redirected.

So basically, I want to feed the first part from an interactive command with a predefined text, and as soon as that text is "consumed" I want to continue using the keyboard (stdin).

Some examples:
Prefill editor and then continue typing manually

```
(echo blablabla; cat) | nano
```

Auto remove first file, then manually confirm removing second file

```
touch dummyfile1.txt; touch dummyfile2.txt
(echo y; cat) | rm -i dummyfile*.txt
```

Fill in password for dummyuser, and than let the user fill in the password for the zip file

```
(echo dummypassword; cat) | su dummyuser -c "unzip pwdprotectedfile.zip"
```

Here, the echo fills in the first part of the command, and then cat takes over to copy stdin to stdout to manually fill in the remaining part of whatever the command needs.

The (echo ; cat) method is the closest thing that (almost) works. But the problem here is that at the end **an extra enter key press is needed to return to the command prompt**.

How to do this properly without the extra key press needed?

The real situation I need this for is to run su -c somecommand, fill in the password automatically (from a secure source) and then let the user answers the questions asked by somecommand.

Comment: What's purpose of the `cat` in the above example?

Comment: @tink: cat without arguments copies stdin to stdout. this is how i switch back to keyboard input after the blablabla string

Comment: `nano <(echo "blablabbla")`

Comment: @Jetchisel Thx, but does not always work. For example read <(echo blablabbla)

Comment: Then update your question.

Comment: @Bigjim : What is the purpose to feed a text editor with the content of a pipe? I guess that this input is supposed to contain editing commands; but wouldn't it then make more sense to use `sed` instead, which is written with the purpose or being operated programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to programmatically generate a content for the `nano` editor, it is as simple as telling nano to edit the standard input by specifying `-` as file name.

```sh
echo "blablabla" | nano -
```

Now consider that `echo` behaviour is not portable across shell versions, so prefer it `printf '%s\n' "blablabla"` for a single line of text.

To be courteous with the user, you can invoke his preferred editor as set in the `EDITOR` environment variable, with fall-back to `vi` if the `EDITOR` environment variable is not set.

```sh
printf '%s\n' "blablabla" | "${EDITOR:-vi}"
```

If you are using bash, you can replace piping `printf` with an [*here-string*](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) instead:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

"${EDITOR:-vi}" - <<<"blablabla"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is not tied to nano, it is just an example. I will update my question with some other examples.